# Coin acceptor misbehave when connected on raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, linux, serial, peripherals, c#

I have a Bill note acceptor and a Coin acceptor, and I have wrote a program in C# to communicate with these two machines, and it worked perfectly on windows, after that I migrated this application to raspbian using mono. the Bill acceptor still works perfectly, but I'm having very weird misbehavior from the coin acceptor summarized by the following:

-when using the coin acceptor alone on the pi, it works sometimes, but with a high rejection rate (which means that the coin acceptor is not recognizing the coins inserted).

-when connecting anything else to the pi's USB ports the coin acceptor stop accepting any coins.

-even though the coin acceptor is rejecting the coins, I don't think there a serial communication problem with the pi, because I'm able to send commands and receive replies.

I'm still new to working with raspberry pi and linux in general, so I hope that someone might have any idea of what might be causing the problem

Note: I'm using the G-13 coin validator from crane payment innovations, and both devices are connect via USB to the Pi for data transfer only (both have there own power adapter).

Comment: Let us know which coin acceptor model you are playing with.  The following AdaFruit coin acceptor tutorialis very good. (1) https://www.adafruit.com/product/786.

Comment: Or watch the following youtube video and read some references: (2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=plG0ZpbN--s
(3) https://www.kr4.us/coin-acceptor-programmable-3-coin-types.html
(4) http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Components/General/3.jpg
(5) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=85355#p602964

Comment: Or show us you C# program list and the Windows tutorial you are following.  It is possible you mono 5 app is not compatible to Rpi4B buster: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/79349/how-to-correctly-error-free-install-mono-5-on-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-stretch.

Comment: Hello, sounds like a power distribution problem. It's not entirely clear from the question but are both devices using USB for data and power? How are you powering them and your Pi? If you have a screen attached are you seeing the low power indicator (i.e "lightning bolt" in top right corner)?

Comment: @tlfong01 I'm using the G-13 coin validator from crane payment innovations, and I'm not following any tutorials, I'm using the documentation I got with the machine

Comment: @RogerJones Hi, I'm using USB for data only, each machine has its own power supply

Comment: Please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/107822/edit) your question and add the additional information you have given in the comments.

Comment: Hi @amm965, I googled and wikied but found the G13 and GDS thing not too open source, so I gave up.  Cheers. (1) G-13 Coin Validator - NRI
http://www.vend-mag.ru/sitefiles/OM_G13mft_USBg_EN_1_1_pdf?file=28/98ef2ed21932f8eaa3cbf5f66905fa45.pdf

(2) GDS - Gaming Device Standards
https://www.gamingstandards.com/en/standards/gds-gaming-device-standards